# What Species of Duck/Waterfowl is this

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I snapped a picture of this beaut in Irvine, CA, but I do not believe it is in the list given in "Ducks at a Distance: A Waterfowl Identification Guide" by Bob Hines (http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/18884). What species of duck is this? I believe it has the shape of a duck, but the colors are unfamiliar to me.

[image]

Comment: Credit to @Sᴋᴜʟʟᴘᴇᴛʀᴏʟ for providing the link to the pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is an [Egyptian Goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_goose) (*Alopochen aegyptiacus*), see the image (First from the Wikipedia article, the second from [here](http://www.birdinginformation.com/birds/geese/egyptian-goose/), interestingly taken in Irvine):

[image]
[image]

You can see the distinctive spot around the eye and also the colored feathers on the back. Also, this bird is too big to be a duck.